# Artifactory API/api/search/versions filter based on file extensions(war, jar, tar.gz)

Tags: maven, jenkins, repository, artifactory, artifactory-query-lang

I am using the below API to fetch all versions of an artifact from Artifactory.

```
https://artifactoryUrl/api/search/versions?g=com.abc.xyz&a=testApp&repos=test-release-local
```

Response

```
{
  "results" : [ {
    "version" : "1.1",
    "integration" : false
  } ]
```

Is there a way we can filter out based on file extensions. We have multiple file extensions like war, jar, tar.gz with same artifact name. I am trying to filter out versions for file testApp.war.

Comment: try the AQL https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+Query+Language

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Artifactory Query Language](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+Query+Language) for that. 
For example:

```
curl -uadmin -XPOST http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/search/aql -T test.json
Enter host password for user 'admin':

{
"results" : [ {
  "repo" : "libs-release-local",
  "path" : "a/a/1.0",
  "name" : "a-1.0.jar",
  "type" : "file",
  "size" : 313,
  "created" : "2020-02-09T11:13:23.266+02:00",
  "created_by" : "admin",
  "modified" : "2020-02-09T11:13:21.469+02:00",
  "modified_by" : "admin",
  "updated" : "2020-02-09T11:13:23.267+02:00"
} ],
"range" : {
  "start_pos" : 0,
  "end_pos" : 1,
  "total" : 1
}
}
```

Inside the test.json you can find my AQL:

$ cat test.json

```
items.find(
    {
        "name":{"$match":"*.jar"}
})
```